# Run Scheduled Job everyday using APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex, job-scheduling

I am trying to make scheduled job using apex code that will run everyday at same time ex. 00:00. According to documentations I need to use slash '/' for increment. So, the string will look something like this:

```
0 0 * /1 * ?
```

But, when I execute this string, the scheduled job is executed every hour. Does anyone have this kind of issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following expression to run the scheduled job daily.

```
0 0 1 * * ?
```

This will run the scheduled job everyday at 1:00AM.

Here is how you read the above expression

**0 = Second**

**0 = Minute**

**1 = Hour**

*** = All days**

*** = All months**

**? = No specific value**

And, I have omitted the optional year part from expression.

Also, you are confusing the `/` which serves completely different purpose.

Docs for: `/`

> Specifies increments. The number before the slash specifies when the intervals will begin, and the number after the slash is the interval amount. For example, if you specify 1/5 for Day_of_month, the Apex class runs every fifth day of the month, starting on the first of the month.